# Alternatives for ScrollView's zoomScale prop for android React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to implement them by myself, but it seems I'm dumb and the best I've done is [this](https://github.com/favorxo/manga-reader-native/blob/main/components/ReaderNative.js).

Anyone knows is there any alternatives for ios's `<ScrollView />` `zoomScale`, `maxZoomScale` and so on, but for android?

Comment: Are you need for ScrollView or just another component example Image (for gallery zoom feature)?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak I need a ScrollView(or FlatList) that has nested scrolling (when the component is zoomed in) and pinch to zoom functions.